# How to analyze Java Swing application using Google Analytics

Tags: java, swing, google-analytics

I have Java Swing application. I need to use Google analytics to get the usage of my application. 
How ca we do that? I know google analytics can be easily incooprate with web application. I am expecting a support for Java Swing application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few Java projects on Github that wrap the Google Analytics HTTP requests:

- google-analytics-java https://github.com/dgomesbr/google-analytics-java
- jgoogleanalytics https://github.com/siddii/jgoogleanalytics

Comment: Finally, I found a usefull example here also.